# Photos.app text search fails to return results for dates by exact, partial, or relative matches

Tags: photos.app, search

**Problem summary:** I expect the Photos text search box to match dates like "November 2022" or "Nov 9" or "on this day" and let me browse results from all photos with at least a partial match. It feels so familiar that I wonder if something changed in a recent Photos update to disable these matches.

- MacBook Pro (2021) running macOS Sonoma 14.0
- Photos app 9.0
- 30K+ photo library on iCloud

I hope these example searches explain what I expected and what it's not providing.

**Example 1:** "Matthew" returns what I expect

- Appearances of "Matthew" as text somewhere in the photo
- Photos tagged with my face

[image: Photos app search results for 'Matthew']

**Example 2:** "Today" shows text matching alone. It fails to show photos *taken* today. I expect search to match relative dates like 'yesterday' (what I took yesterday) or 'on this date' (all photos taken November 9, regardless of year).

[image: Photos app search for 'today']

**Example 3:** "Nov 9" fails to match photos taken on November 9, regardless of year. I feel sure this was available before. This search helps me find a full set of event photos based on the date of a single photo from the past.

[image: Photos app search for the partial date 'Nov 9']

If date searches work for you, did you adjust something in Photos or macOS to make that possible? Let me know if you need more info.